# I am trying to make CSS work on mobile browsers

Tags: forms, css, button, input

My CSS is working perfectly fine on Google Chrome, Mozilla, and Opera. I have also tried Internet Explorer but that was a bust - Not that it matters.

My biggest issue right now is getting my CSS to work correctly on mobile safari (and other smartphone browsers like android).

HTML:

```css
.load-more {
      background-color: #00aa00;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: block;
      font-family: 'Numans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: lighter;
      height: 3em;
      line-height: 3em;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0 3em;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: all .2s ease, background-color .01s ease, color .01s ease;
      border-bottom: none;
    }

    .load-more.load-more--loading {
      animation: rotate 1.5s linear infinite;
      animation-delay: .2s;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: .3em solid #e1e1e1;
      border-radius: 1.5em;
      border-top-color: #00aa00;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 3em;
      color: transparent;
      padding: 0;
      pointer-events: none;
      width: 3em;
      -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
    }


    @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
      from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
      }
    }
```

```html
<form action="stats.php" method="GET">
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" name="player" autocomplete="off"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
    <label>USERNAME</label>
  </div>
  <center>
    <input type="submit" value="CHECK STATS" class="load-more">
    </a>
  </center>
</form>
```

The CSS (and a javascript file that I'm using) turn the button into a loader when you click on it, but on mobile browsers like safari the button just disappears when you click it with no loader.

Example: https://epicmc.us

Comment: it is working fine on firefox and opera

Comment: Okay cool! Any idea as to what CSS I'm missing to make it function on mobile safari?

Comment: Very cool effect and great UX here too, by the way. Keeps the label above the field when the placeholder disappears so you don't forget what you're entering.

Answer (score 1):

There's some support in iOS 7 and 8 for transform but none for animation in iOS. You're going to have to use jQuery or something to get the effect to work in mobile safari. Caniuse.com tells us the support here for these attributes: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: Okay cool thanks! I am going to fool around with jquery and post a solution on this thread a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS works perfectly on mobile safari...

```
.load-more {
  background-color: #00aa00;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Numans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 3em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  }
  .load-more.load-more--loading {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: .3em solid #e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  border-top-color: #00aa00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 3em;
  color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 3em;
  -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}
  }
```

Comment: Are you using iOS 7 or 8?

Comment: I am on iOS 8 and the above CSS modification made it work just fine.

Comment: Cool what did you modify? (see my earlier post, caniuse shows only iOS 7 and 8 support for transform and animation in mobile safari).